# Sidebar cut off by footer

Tags: html, css, footer, sidebar

I'm working on my own website, which is still very, very amateur, but I ran into a problem which I can't seem to solve on my own.

I just added a side bar with content (nothing special, just some filler text), but the footer cuts off the text of my sidebar, but not the main content's text.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="main">
        <h1>PHP</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <h2>Sidebar</h2>

        <p>
        Hello, this is just some filler tekst. Blablabla blabl blabla blabla blblbla blablalbabla blablalbl.<br>
        <br>
        As you can see, it's positioned well.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
<p>Made by me 2014</p>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS for the stuff:

```
#content {
background          :   linear-gradient(#669900, #66FF99); /* Gradient -                        Standaard */
background          :   -moz-linear-gradient(#669900, #66FF99); /* Gradient  - Firefox */
background-repeat   :   no-repeat;
background-attachment:  fixed;
/*margin-left       :   185.5px;
  margin-right      :   185.5px;*/
margin              :   0 auto;
width               :   980px;
position            :   relative;
padding             :   20px 0 25px 0;
border-left         :   5px solid lightgreen;
border-right        :   5px solid lightgreen;
}

#main {
padding             :   0 30px 0 30px;
margin-right        :   200px;
}

#sidebar {
position            :   absolute;
top                 :   0;
bottom              :   0;
left                :   780px;
width               :   180px;
float               :   right;
margin              :   0 10px 0 10px;
overflow            :   auto;
}

#sidebar h2 {
text-align          :   center;
margin-left         :   -15px;
}
```

Sorry, I know it's a lot to read, but I hope you can help.

My problem is: The footer doesn't move with the text in the side bar, it cuts it off, but it does move when there's text added in the main div.

Can anyone help?

Max

Comment: take away `overflow:auto;`

Comment: Is [>>> it (click :: JSFiddle)<<<](http://jsfiddle.net/AvBy7/) the effect, you want to get?

Comment: @BeatAlex: I've put it there to try and fix it, forgot to take it away. Didn't fix it. :P

Comment: @Benio: Yes. That is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

same problem but on changing position from absolute to relative the sidebar moved below the posts

```
.sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 25px 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border: medium none;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Add some more description to your answer.

Comment: Bro visit this link and go to the bottom of that page http://www.blogolectlab2.blogspot.com
sidebar is overlapping footer